# Why is 'H' / 72 / 0x48 the second most common byte in executables?

Tags: x86, elf

<sup>(If the score of this question is 72, please don't upvote!)</sup>

I ran this:

```bash
cat /usr/bin/* |
  perl -ne 'map {$a{$_}++} split//; END{print map { "$a{$_}\t$_\n" } keys %a}' |
  grep --text . | sort -n | plotpipe --log y {1}
```

and got this:

[image: number of occurences of byte value]

(Even with a log y-axis it still looks exponential! There is more than 100x between the top and the bottom)

Looking at the numbers:

```
:
31919597        ^H
32983719        ^B
33943030        ^O
39130281        \213
39893389        $
52237360        \211
53229196        ^A
76884442        \377
100776756       H
746405320       ^@
```

It is hardly surprising that ^@ (NUL) is the most common byte in executables. \377 (255) and ^A (1) also make intuitively sense to me.

But what causes 'H' (72) to be the second most common byte in executables - far more common than 255 and 1?

**Background**

For a Perl script, I needed to find the least common byte in Perl scripts. By accident, I didn't grep out only Perl scripts but ran the command on all binaries. I expected a few bytes to stand out, such as NUL, 1, and 255, but never 'H'.

The input for the graph is the count of each byte, sorted. The y-axis represents the count, and the x-axis represents the line number (1-256, as a byte can only take on 256 different values). The y-axis is log scale, so the difference is bigger than exponential.

Comment: Personally I find this question interesting, but the [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) is clear: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". Now I'm curious: what is the *actual problem* here?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I think that's mostly in reference to open-ended opinion-based questions and such. Even if oddities like this weren't that relevant to any single issue at hand, they may still have some clear technical reason in the background. And the answer may be _interesting_.

Comment: anyway, if we took that restriction strictly, pretty much all questions about history would be forbidden. ("why was this designed like this?" - "do you have a _problem_ about that?")

Comment: @ilkkachu In good faith I assume all such questions are based on actual problems; and I assume the same here. The difference is here I'm more curious what the actual problem is; curious enough to ask. I suspect the answer to *this* (if my assumption is right and the answer exists) may be more interesting *to me* than any technical answer below. Of course it's Ole's courtesy if I get my answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, mm. Yes, it would be interesting to know how this came up, even if it's not about a _problem_ as such. But I have an unhealthy interest in irrelevant oddities too, so.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Also worth noting I think that this looks somewhat like boilerplate that is common across all of the SE sites. Like this may be somewhat less applicable on sites like Code Golf.

Comment: @JustineKrejcha, heh, since you mention it, it's amusing to note that e.g. both [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (rife with history questions) have the exact same text. So fixed boilerplate it indeed appears to be.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Given the evidence that it's pretty much boilerplate and even codegolf has the text, "practical" must mean "able to judge the quality of an answer".

Comment: This seems like it would fit better on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/.  (It's not strictly a programming question, so some SO users might object, but there are quite a few how-CPUs-work questions there which we consider on-topic.  Tags like [x86-64][assembly][machine-code][reverse-engineering] would work on SO.)  @ilkkachu - any thoughts on flagging this for migration to https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/?  I think probably not, that should only get done if it was actually off-topic for this site, and I agree it's ok here.

Comment: @PeterCordes, oh don't ask me, I don't particularly mind either way. If you flag it, I suppose the mods get to make a call. :)

Comment: Sorry for being dumb (I am not versed in perl and regexps) but would you mind indicating what the x and y axis in your graph represent ?

Comment: Though perhaps not directly relevant, this reminds me of "Benford's Law", which gives an explanation why "1" is a far more common leading digit of numbers (that appear in real life)... :)

Comment: @MC68020, the Perl snippet breaks the input into bytes and counts each distinct value, the output is lines with the count and the byte. Sorted, they're plotted, and I think the x-axis is just indexes after the sort (so lowest value on the left), and the y-axis is the counts (on a log scale). Eyeballing at the ends of the very last, very vertical line segment, the rightmost values might be something like 0.8*10^9, and 1*10^8. (Which just so happen to correspond to the numbers listed. I can't tell apart the third point that should be at 0.76*10^8, though.)

Comment: @MC68020, you can try something like `printf 'abbbcc' | perl -ne 'map {$a{$_}++} split//; END{print map { "$a{$_}\t$_\n" } keys %a}' | grep --text . | sort -n` to see what the pipeline prints. I'm not familiar with `plotpipe`, but I suppose the `{1}` just refers to the first column. The listing in the Q looks like it's been additionally passed through something like `cat -v`, though, that doesn't seem to be shown.

Comment: plotpipe: https://codeberg.org/tange/tangetools/src/branch/master/plotpipe

Comment: That `cat` is useless, but you already know that.

Comment: `od -An -w1 -vtu1 /usr/bin/* | sort -n | uniq -c | gnuplot -p -e 'set term png size 1200,200; set xrange [1:254]; set xtics 0,+16,256; set format x "0x%02X"; plot "-" using 2:1 with impulses notitle' > report.png` might have been more useful at showing 0x48 as an outlier.

Comment: Do I have to downvote now as it is over 72 upvotes?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

That would be the *64 bit operand size prefix* of amd64 machine code instructions.

You'll notice it only happens on amd64 executables.

If you compare on the `/bin/*` of http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_9.1-1_arm64.deb,
http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_9.1-1_amd64.deb and
http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_9.1-1_i386.deb, you'll see:

```
$ for f (coreutils_9.1-1_*.deb) bsdtar xOf $f da\* | bsdtar xO ./bin/\* | xxd -p -c1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 5 | grep -H --label="${${f:r}##*_}" .
amd64: 692417 00
amd64: 145689 ff
amd64:  81911 48
amd64:  48006 89
amd64:  45331 0f
arm64:1409826 00
arm64:  70391 ff
arm64:  67915 03
arm64:  49380 20
arm64:  41655 40
i386: 515346 00
i386: 171643 ff
i386:  78361 0e
i386:  69317 24
i386:  50497 83
```

0x48 (72, 'H') is only in the top 3 on amd64.

On `ls` on my amd64 Debian system:

```
$ xxd -p -c1 =ls | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 5
  39187 00
   7827 ff
   5565 48
   4181 20
   3393 0f
```

If we disassemble the code in that executable, we find a lot of 0x48 bytes in the instructions:

```
$ objdump -d =ls | grep -cw 48
5353
```

Most of them in first position:

```
$ objdump -d =ls | grep -wm10 48
    4000:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    4004:       48 8b 05 ad ff 01 00    mov    0x1ffad(%rip),%rax        # 23fb8 <__gmon_start__@Base>
    400b:       48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
    4012:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
    44b6:       68 48 00 00 00          push   $0x48
    4751:       48 89 f3                mov    %rsi,%rbx
    4754:       48 83 ec 68             sub    $0x68,%rsp
    4758:       48 8b 3e                mov    (%rsi),%rdi
    475b:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    4764:       48 89 44 24 58          mov    %rax,0x58(%rsp)
```

```
$ objdump -d =ls | grep -Pc '^\s*[\da-f]+:\s+48'
5113
```

According to http://ref.x86asm.net/geek.html#x48, that 0x48 is the *64 Bit Operand Size* `REX.W` opcode prefix which specify that the operation is to be made on 64 bit operands instead of whatever default it's meant to be.

```
$ objdump -d =ls | pcregrep -o1 -o2 '^\s*[\da-f]+:\s+(48 .. ).*?\t(\S+)' | sort | uniq -c  | sort -rn | head
   1512 48 89 mov
   1040 48 8b mov
    630 48 8d lea
    372 48 85 test
    326 48 83 add
    198 48 39 cmp
    158 48 83 sub
     79 48 01 add
     72 48 83 cmp
     69 48 c7 movq
```

All instructions done on 64 bit operands.

Comment: Wow that `0E` as the third most common on i386 is baffling. As an opcode it's `push cs` (which is a 1 byte opcode). `24` is and, which is sensible, `83` is `adc` with a memory address and immediate operands, which is unexpected.

Comment: @Joshua `83` is any `alu r/m32, imm8`, with the operation depending on the ModRM byte that follows, it's not specifically `adc`. `24` is also a useful SIB byte (most memory operands that have `esp` as the base), probably more common in that usage than as `and al, imm8` (which is not a useless operation either but using 8-bit registers in that way is not super common)

Comment: Just when I didn't think Intel instruction sets and encodings could be any stupider.